# In Friends, do Monica and co. live above Central Perk?

Tags: friends

In *Friends*, I always imagined that Central Perk was located on the ground floor of the building that Monica, Rachel, Joey, and Chandler lived in.

However, I can't remember anything in the show that actually confirms that — nor anything that directly contradicts it.

A [Greenwich Village Society for Historic Preservation blog post](https://www.villagepreservation.org/2011/09/22/so-no-one-told-you-life-was-gonna-be-this-way-2/) (referenced in [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3904/where-are-monica-and-chandlers-apartments/3909#3909)) states that Central Perk was on the ground floor of the building, but doesn't include anything to support the assertion.

Can we finally put the world's mind at rest by nailing this down?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I've watched the series in its entirety multiple times, and I don't remember anything explicitly answering that question.

There is, however, a scene in season one's *[The One With George Stephanopoulos](https://friends.fandom.com/wiki/The_One_With_George_Stephanopoulos)* where Joey enters the coffee shop and he states that there are 97 steps from their flat to the coffee shop. Again, that's not a definite answer, but considering they are multiple floors up and have to go down many steps just to reach the ground floor, 97 steps mean that if not above, their apartments are at least a very close neighbour.

Slightly more conclusive, in another episode, before leaving the coffee shop to return home, Monica says to Rachel that she'll "see [her] upstairs".

Although never explicitly and directly said, it is heavily and almost conclusively implied.

Comment: Aha! Yes, of course, 97 steps. That plus the "see you upstairs" reference pretty much nails it I'd say.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I remain unconvinced. It just means "up in the apartment" rather than literally up the stairs from their present location.

Comment: 60 stairs per floor?  How tall are those floors?  Those buildings are old enough to not necessarily be compatible with modern building standards, but I'd expect an average riser to not be outside the range of 15-20cm.   So 60 riser heights would be 9-12m, which I'd expect to be at least 3 floors.

Comment: @Valorum - I would not describe a location as simply "upstairs" unless it was in the same building. To me that implies the apartment are accessible internally from the coffee shop, l.e without going outside, and is therfore part of the same building.

Comment: @Ethan - that's a very literal way of looking at it. Certainly we never see any inkling that there's any way to access the coffee shop internally. At best you need to leave and then go up some stairs ("upstairs") to get to their apartment

Comment: 20 stairs per floor (a total of 60). Five steps from the apartment door to the staircase and say ten steps to the main entrance. That leaves 25 steps to take them to Central Perk. It's certainly very close, but not necessarily in the same building. Possibly opposite or next door

Comment: @Valorum: I see your points, I agree it's not conclusive. (Although you have a small math error — by your reckons, it's 22 steps from the apartment building entrance to Central Perk.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - It should say 10-ish steps to the main entrance.

Comment: @Ethan: "To me that implies the apartment are accessible internally from the coffee shop" — I doubt that the apartments are meant to accessible from the coffee shop without going outside — aside from real-world practical concerns, we always seem to see the characters leave Central Perk by the door that goes out onto the street. If they are meant to be located in the same building, I'd expect the apartments to have their own street entrance.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Agreed. While it's not uncommon for shops to have internal entrances in office buildings, it would be weird in a residential apartment building.

Comment: Don't forget the couple of steps you take at each landing of the stairway. In my building there are two flights (20 vertical steps) between each floor, and that almost always takes me 24 steps (20+2*2 landings). 97 steps would be four flights at the most, and realistically three (24*3=72) with a few steps starting and ending.

Comment: My office is on the 8th floor of a building downtown. If a coworker and I were having lunch within a block or so off the office, and he said that he had to run a few errands before going back to work, I could *easily* picture myself saying "ok, you go on ahead, I'll meet you upstairs." Perhaps with a little head nod or hand wave in the vague direction of the office. All of that would mean that I'd meet him in the office, not upstairs in the restaurant's building.

Comment: In "The One with the Chicken Pox", Ross shows up to the cafe in a Navy uniform for Rachael. He intends to carry her to the apartment, so it is presumably very close. Ross ends up carrying her back and forth across the room a few times as she remembers things she needs to do that she forgot, before ultimately dropping her on the couch and saying "alright you know, why don't I just meet you upstairs." I doubt he would carry her down the street unless it was only a few steps into the apartment building's lobby. https://www.livesinabox.com/friends/season2/223towcp.htm

Comment: @DavidW You couldn't just Google that kind of thing back in '94. Can you imagine the writers making phone calls to a city planner or architect, like "hello, can you tell me the number of stairs per floor specified by building standards? I need to finish a script!" ...Driven by a nagging feeling that people on the internet are going to care about the accuracy of it 30 years in the future. If they were that diligent, kudos - but I think we should also consider the possibility that the 97 steps figure is an approximation, and also that the *character* Joey wasn't required to be precisely correct.

Comment: The 97 steps comes from "95, 96, 97. See, I told you! Less than 100 steps from our place"
That could be the apartment building front door - whatever definition of "our place" they wanted to accept - and as it is Joey proving it is less than "100" - could and probably would mean taking enormous strides - I'd be jumping down a flight of stairs and claiming it as 1 step and taking over 2m per stride.  Which could place it as much as 2 blocks over.

Comment: @Ethan As a life-long New Yorker, I assure you that “upstairs” can easily just mean “home” to people living in the same apartment. Probably wouldn’t be used if it were a long trip just to get to the building, but being already in the building itself is absolutely unnecessary. “I’ll see you upstairs” is absolutely not conclusive evidence at all.

Answer (score 6):

There have been several fan-made attempts at floor plans for the apartments and Central Perk.

None of these appear to share any distinctive external wall patterns.  That doesn't conclusively say they're not in the same building, but doesn't provide evidence they are.

We also can't look to real life either, because [Grove Street in New York stops at around street number 70.](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.733725,-74.0016149,3a,75y,244.99h,95.32t/data=!3m10!1e1!3m8!1sHUAgVhEEUkUcqGlzJ5kgqw!2e0!6shttps:%2F%2Fstreetviewpixels-pa.googleapis.com%2Fv1%2Fthumbnail%3Fpanoid%3DHUAgVhEEUkUcqGlzJ5kgqw%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D272.30292%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i16384!8i8192!9m2!1b1!2i48?entry=ttu) so the address is completely fictitious.

[image: Central Perk]

SOURCE  https://www.deviantart.com/nikneuk/art/Floorplan-of-the-Central-Perk-from-FRIENDS-873833711

[image]

SOURCE https://www.deviantart.com/nikneuk/art/FRIENDS-Apartment-s-Floorplans-New-Version-509938534

Comment: These plans are fan-made and have little or no bearing on what the makers of the show had in mind.

Comment: It's interesting to see these. Accurate or not, it shows how dedicated fans can be. Any expectation that TV or film set layouts be reproducible in real life is unrealistic anyway. May as well enjoy the effort the fans put in, without reading into it too deeply.

Comment: That said, [Comic Sans is criminal](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38226/), and so is sizing the ampersands to be the largest part of the text.

Comment: @Mentalist totally agree - that's why I've clearly left the source link visible.

Comment: Although the plans are fan-made, they look to be closely based on what we see in the show, so if we’re just trying to interpret what’s on-screen, I say they’re interesting and worth looking at.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite concur - I was hoping to find a clear outline of the building footprint that would have "stacked"    Lack of evidence is not evidence unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah I mean in my head the street entrance for the _Friends_ friends' apartments is around the corner from Central Perk, and their apartment windows may be on the other side of the building entirely. (I'm not familiar with Greenwich Village in real life, so I'm not clear how likely any of this is in reality.)